# Excel Pivot when cells are already summed

Tags: excel, pivot

Halo everyone.

I have a table looking like this:
[image: What I have]

But would like to get to the following setup:
[image: What I want]

I have tried using a pivot table and used "ids" as rows, "event" as columns and "hits" as values.
This would lead to the same setup as the last picture but with 1's replacing the actual "hits".
How do I correct these 1's to the actual number of hits?

Comment: Excel is probably returning the `Count` instead of the `Sum` for the column. Edit the column type of the pivot table so it returns the sum instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to my comment and merge:

Excel is probably returning the Count instead of the Sum for the column. Edit the column type of the pivot table so it returns the sum instead

[image]

Comment: Meh.... You can have this one.  I am feeling lazy today.  I deleted mine.

Comment: This is what i normally would do but in this case it would lead to 0's instead of 1's.

Comment: @NicolaiIversen what? Tom and I got the exact output you asked for with sum, no `0`s.  Can you explain more your comment, as it does not make sense.

Comment: Okay so I got the data from the web and forgot to specify it as numbers instead of strings. Hence the zeros. When correcting for this your suggestion lead to the solution.